# how to print this number in a shortest time using thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

this is my code :

```
import thread

k=0
b=0
def a(n):
    i = 0
    while i<n:
        print i
        i += 1

j = 5000

while k < 5000:
    a(k)
    k+=1
for n in range(2,5):
    thread.start_new_thread(a,(j*n,))
```

and i want to Run three threads and a main thread，

```
the main thread print 1,2,3,4,5,....5000
and the thread1 print 5001,5002,5003,...10000
the thread2 print 10001,10002,10003,...15000
the thread3 print 15001,15002,15003,...20000

they are at the same time
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: This seems to be a very contrived example. There is only minimal (if any) gain here from using threads.

Comment: Smells like Homework or a Tutorial example...

Comment: @Space @Bobby It's a contrived example because the real problem is how to do a brute force password attack on a website. OP's question earlier today on that subject was deleted.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Oh, that explains it...I wonder if this question gets also deleted because you've biased it now. ;P

Comment: Well it's hard to stop someone disguising what they are doing, but @zjm1126 should at least feel a bit of shame. The deleted post was utterly shameful! I don't see any reason why this should be deleted.

Comment: The news of a [hack](http://tinkode27.baywords.com/mysql-com-fr-it-de-jp-full-disclosure-hacked-by-tinkode-and-ne0h/) at MySQL.com revealing users with passwords all digits passwords resonates!

Answer (score 0):

You should use threading instead of thread, since it's easier to implement and it works in almost every case. Now your code will be like:

```
import threading 

class PrintNumber(Thread):
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.n = n

  def run(self):
    for i in range(n, n+5000):
      print i

# create your threads here
# use a cicle if needed
thread = PrintNumber(0) # first 5000 numbers
thread.start()
thread = PrintNumber(5000) # next 5000
thread.start()
```

Coded from mind and have not tested it, should be working anyway